# How to get distinct rows based on multiple columns are include the latest row from another table?

Tags: sql, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

I have a `users` table and a `private_messages` table, I want to get a list of users where the current user has sent or received a message from another user together with the latest message content.

users table

`id | username`

private_messages table

`author_id | recipient_id | content | creation_date`

This is the closest i got to getting the users

```sql
SELECT u.id, u.username FROM users u
WHERE u.id IN 
    (SELECT p.author_id as id
     FROM private_messages p
     WHERE p.recipient_id = '6d480813-c854-40fc-a3cf-cea0944854ab' 
    );
```

but as you can see it only counts if the user is not the author of the message and also I don't know how to include the content of the latest message.

Being new to SQL, I'm also up to changing the model of the table.

users table data

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════╗
║                  "id"                  ║   "username"   ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════╣
║ "2f8afc87-13d3-4654-8333-465b094c9ccf" ║ "KayleeSchumm" ║
║ "e5e37e98-3468-47e1-9c7e-1311988d6d79" ║ "JordonWaters" ║
║ "6d480813-c854-40fc-a3cf-cea0944854ab" ║ "AsafAviv"     ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════╝
```

private_messages data

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════════════════════════════╦═════════════════╦══════════════════════════════╗
║              "author_id"               ║             "recipient_id"             ║    "content"    ║       "creation_date"        ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════════════════════════════╬═════════════════╬══════════════════════════════╣
║ "2f8afc87-13d3-4654-8333-465b094c9ccf" ║ "e5e37e98-3468-47e1-9c7e-1311988d6d79" ║ "hello world 0" ║ "2020-04-14 14:01:40.121+03" ║
║ "2f8afc87-13d3-4654-8333-465b094c9ccf" ║ "6d480813-c854-40fc-a3cf-cea0944854ab" ║ "hello world 0" ║ "2020-04-14 14:01:40.121+03" ║
║ "e5e37e98-3468-47e1-9c7e-1311988d6d79" ║ "2f8afc87-13d3-4654-8333-465b094c9ccf" ║ "hello world 0" ║ "2020-04-14 14:01:40.121+03" ║
║ "e5e37e98-3468-47e1-9c7e-1311988d6d79" ║ "6d480813-c854-40fc-a3cf-cea0944854ab" ║ "hello world 0" ║ "2020-04-14 14:01:40.121+03" ║
║ "6d480813-c854-40fc-a3cf-cea0944854ab" ║ "2f8afc87-13d3-4654-8333-465b094c9ccf" ║ "hello world 0" ║ "2020-04-14 14:01:40.121+03" ║
║ "6d480813-c854-40fc-a3cf-cea0944854ab" ║ "e5e37e98-3468-47e1-9c7e-1311988d6d79" ║ "hello world 0" ║ "2020-04-14 14:01:40.121+03" ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════════════════════════════╩═════════════════╩══════════════════════════════╝
```

expected output

```
╔════════════════════════════════════════╦════════════════╦═════════════════╗
║                  "id"                  ║   "username"   ║    "content"    ║
╠════════════════════════════════════════╬════════════════╬═════════════════╣
║ "2f8afc87-13d3-4654-8333-465b094c9ccf" ║ "KayleeSchumm" ║ "hello world 0" ║
║ "e5e37e98-3468-47e1-9c7e-1311988d6d79" ║ "JordonWaters" ║ "hello world 0" ║
╚════════════════════════════════════════╩════════════════╩═════════════════╝
```

Comment: Sample data and desired results would help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, p.content 
FROM users u
INNER JOIN (
  SELECT DISTINCT
    CASE WHEN p.author_id = '6d480813-c854-40fc-a3cf-cea0944854ab' THEN p.recipient_id ELSE p.author_id END user_id,
    p.content
  FROM private_messages p
  WHERE '6d480813-c854-40fc-a3cf-cea0944854ab' IN (p.author_id, p.recipient_id)
  AND NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT 1 FROM private_messages
    WHERE (author_id, recipient_id) IN ((p.author_id, p.recipient_id), (p.recipient_id, p.author_id))
      AND creation_date > p.creation_date
  )                                                                         
) p ON u.id = p.user_id
```

The query joined to `users` uses `NOT EXISTS` to return the last message to each of the users.
See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/uYw8UKbUTaU5CyVtStBYUm/0).
Or with `CTE`s and `ROW_NUMBER()` window function:

```
WITH 
  cur_user(id) AS (VALUES('6d480813-c854-40fc-a3cf-cea0944854ab')),
  cte_all AS (
    SELECT content, creation_date,
      CASE (SELECT id FROM cur_user)
        WHEN author_id THEN recipient_id
        ELSE author_id
      END user_id
    FROM private_messages 
    WHERE (SELECT id FROM cur_user) IN (author_id, recipient_id)
  ),
  cte_last AS (
    SELECT t.content, t.creation_date, t.user_id
    FROM (
      SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY creation_date) rn
      FROM cte_all
    ) t
    WHERE t.rn = 1 
  )  
SELECT u.id, u.username, c.content 
FROM users u INNER JOIN cte_last c
ON c.user_id = u.id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/bEhY2xYvpgniem8F8n7iL1/3).
Results:

```
| id                                   | username     | content       |
| ------------------------------------ | ------------ | ------------- |
| 2f8afc87-13d3-4654-8333-465b094c9ccf | KayleeSchumm | hello world 0 |
| e5e37e98-3468-47e1-9c7e-1311988d6d79 | JordonWaters | hello world 0 |
```

Comment: This works but I also get duplicate users from messages that the current user sent

Comment: It would help if you posted sample data in tabular format so I can check what you mean by duplicates.

Comment: Or even better create a fiddle here: https://www.db-fiddle.com with sample data.

Comment: I've edited the post(more cleaner now), do you want to me to include the results of your query?

Comment: See my edited answer. I added DISTINCT in the subquery.

Comment: Fine if it works. Now that I have the sample data I will try another solution with window function which may be more efficient.

Comment: Check another solution that may be faster.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
SELECT u.id, u.username, pm.*
FROM users u CROSS JOIN
     (values ('6d480813-c854-40fc-a3cf-cea0944854ab')
     ) as v(the_user) CROSS JOIN LATERAL
     (SELECT DISTINCT ON (v2.other_user) pm.*
      FROM private_messages pm CROSS JOIN LATERAL
           (VALUES (CASE WHEN pm.recipient_id = v.the_user
                         THEN pm.author_id ELSE pm.recipient_id
                   END)
           ) v2(other_user)
      WHERE v.the_user = v2.other_user
      ORDER BY v2.other_user, pm.creation_date desc
     ) pm;
```

The `VALUES()` clauses are just a convenience for handling the constant user value.

The key part is the `DISTINCT ON`.  This returns the first row for each "other user" based on the `ORDER BY`.  In this case, the `ORDER BY` puts the most recent record first.